# search and reapply ( kindof )

Tags: php, jquery

So I have a list of links that show the relationship of the link to a URL

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Mary Jones</a>
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Sam</a>
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Jill</a>
```

I need a quick jQuery or PHP that will apply those links to a document like this

```
Jill    
Sam
Mary Jones
Jill
```

so the result would be

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Jill</a>
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Sam</a>
<a href="http://www.google.com">Mary Jones</a>
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Jill</a>
```

Comment: What part do you need help with ? What is your question ?

Comment: "I need a quick jQuery or PHP that will apply those links to a document like this"

Comment: when you say "document like this" what kind of document is it?  Is it DOM, word doc, pdf, or google doc?

Comment: And do you want the result printed to a file? Do you need help reading the file? What have you tried? We need some more information.

Comment: I have a huge document like the first with links, I don't want to format it. Then I have another huge document that looks like the second where I want to apply the links. The result should show the last, it doesn't need to print to a file, I just need a way to automate this redundant task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with php by opening the first file, creating a map, and then opening the second file and applying the map.  It has been a while since I used php, so I will leave that for others.  The first part would look something like this:

```
$file = file_get_contents('./linksfile', true);
$links = preg_split("/[\n\r]+/",$file);

$linkMap = array();
foreach ( $links as $link ) {
    # NOTE! regex and xml is generally BAD, 
    # but if you have a fixed format it will do the job:
    $name = preg_replace('/\<.*?\>/g', '', $link);
    $linkMap[ $name ] = $link;
}
```

Then you would need to apply that map, as others have shown in their answers.

If you want `jQuery`, you could do something like this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/QTZNK/

You would have to modify it if you are working on two files, and I'm not sure what your final output needs to be, but this demonstrates another way things could be done.

Comment: thank you so much ! I ended up going with the jQuery version and it worked perfectly !

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you already know how to read in the file of names:

```
<?php
$lookup = array (
    'Jill' => 'http://www.stackoverflow.com',
    'Sam' => 'http://www/yahoo.com',
    'Mary Jones' => 'http://www.google.com',
)

foreach ($names as $name) {
    echo "<a href='" . $lookup[$name] ."'>$name</a>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this requires work to format the document int an array, can it do some detection to find the links? maybe regex?

Answer (score 1):

```
$input = array(
    '<a href="http://www.google.com">Mary Jones</a>',
    '<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Sam</a>',
    '<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Jill</a>'
);

$urlsMap = array();
foreach ( $input as $url ) {
    $name = stripslashes($url);
    $urlsMap[ $name ] = $url;
}

$relationship = array(
    'Jill',
    'Sam',
    'Mary Jones',
    'Jill'
);

$output = array();
foreach ( $relationship as $name ) {
    if ( isset( $urlsMap[ $name ] ) ) {
        $output[] = $urlsMap[ $name ];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this requires work to format the document int an array, can it do some detection to find the links? maybe regex?

Comment: Use `SimpleXML` to convert HTML to object and then iterate it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use regex:

```
<?php

$links =
'<a href="http://www.google.com">Mary Jones</a>
<a href="http://www.yahoo.com">Sam</a>
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">Jill</a>';

$text = preg_match_all('/<a href="([a-zA-Z]+[:\/\/]+[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\\.+[A-Za-z0-9\.\/%&=\?\-_]+)">([A-Za-z ]+)<\/a>/i', $links, $matches);

$tomatch = array('Jill', 'Sam', 'Mary Jones', 'Jill');

for( $i = 0, $l = count( $matches[0] ); $i < $l; $i++ )
  $corr[$matches[2][$i]] = $matches[1][$i];

foreach( $tomatch as $m )
  echo '<a href="'.$corr[$m].'">'.$m.'</a><br />';

?>
```